# package read from module (jar) that does not contain it

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system

Modularizing an existing project I have run into the following problem:

javac (java 10 or 11) complains:

```
[ERROR] module org.apache.commons.lang3 reads package javax.xml.soap from both java.xml.ws and java.xml.soap
```

(this error occurs for a lot of other modules)

So it says that package "java.xml.soap" comes from "java.xml.ws" module. Right?

This is what

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

tells me about java.xml.ws:

```
javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.3.1:compile -- module java.xml.ws
```

And when I look into jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar, there are only packages starting with "javax.xml.ws". But no "java.xml.soap".

describing the module through jar command reveals the following:

```
$ jar --file=jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar --describe-module
java.xml.ws jar:file:///C:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/javax/xml/ws/jaxws-api/2.3.1/jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar/!module-info.class
exports javax.xml.ws
exports javax.xml.ws.handler
exports javax.xml.ws.handler.soap
exports javax.xml.ws.http
exports javax.xml.ws.soap
exports javax.xml.ws.spi
exports javax.xml.ws.spi.http
exports javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing
requires java.annotation
requires java.base mandated
requires java.logging
requires java.xml.bind
requires java.xml.soap
uses javax.xml.ws.spi.Invoker
uses javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
uses javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceDelegate
uses javax.xml.ws.spi.WebServiceFeatureAnnotation
```

So why is javac complaining?

Comment: use `jar --file=jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar--describe-module` to see does it export the package `javax.xml.soap` or not.

Comment: can't get formatting right in comment; however, --describe-module does not export java.xml.soap (it only requires java.xml.soap) - updated question as suggested by naman

Comment: Please update the question with the details as an editt.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague has provided changes to our project which made the issue go away.

Will have to investigate what the actual fix is, right now my assumption is that is has to do with java ee vs. jakarta ee which is definitely a good source of confusing name clashes.

Comment: excluding javax.mail:mail everywhere and using jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api instead was the solution. did not investigate further.